# Can record sound using Microphone once, but cannot start microphone second time

Tags: java, audio, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am using the CMU sphinx library to record sound. When i begin my java application, I allocate the Recognizer and the Configuration Manager only once as follows:

```
        cm = new ConfigurationManager(soundPart.class.getResource("hellongram.config.xml"));
        recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        recognizer.allocate();
```

Moreover, I have a record sound button in my application. When the user clicks it, I use the below code to record sound :

```
    Microphone microphone = (Microphone)MR.sp.cm.lookup("microphone");
    if (!microphone.startRecording()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
        MR.sp.recognizer.deallocate();

        System.exit(1);
    }
    //MR.sp.pleaseStartSpeaking.setVisible(true);
    while(true){
    Result result = MR.sp.recognizer.recognize();
    if(result!=null){
        String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
        MR.sp.lblYouSearched.setVisible(true);
        MR.sp.lblNewLabel.setVisible(true);
        MR.sp.lblNewLabel.setText(resultText);
        MR.textQuery = resultText.toLowerCase();
        break;
    }
    }
```

This works the first time I do it. However, if the user clicks the record button the second time, it throws the error "Cannot start microphone". What I am doing wrong here. WHy can't I acquire the microphone the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into Microphone's RecordingThread [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/edu/cmu/sphinx/frontend/util/Microphone.RecordingThread.html) as well as re-read the page where you got that code [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/ProgrammersGuide.html) since the difference between the code you used and what you want to do is the code you used doesn't start and stop the microphone, it's continuously recording. A RecordingThread looks to be what you're after since you can easily call start() and stop() to get what you're after.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code please. Just looking at the documentation is not helping me much

Comment: Moreover, in my above code, whenever i want to record, i get the microphone. What is wrong with this?